# Capturar cookie setado

Tags: php, cookies

Estou desenvolvendo um sistema e minha ideia é utilizar cookies para salvar os dados (pelo menos os de login).

Eu tenho a página de login (login.php), e um JavaScript enviando os dados via AJAX da página de login para o PHP (data.php).

No PHP, ele chama o método `Login` e efetua o mesmo. Após logar, antes de dar retorno ao JavaScript, eu inicializo diversos cookies, mas após logar, em qualquer outra página, eu não consigo acessar eles. Abaixo está o código:

**data.php**

```
$login = $Admin->login($admin["txtMail"], $admin["txtPassword"]);
if(!$login){
    echo json_encode([
        "success"       => false,
        "description"   => "incorrect data"
    ]);
}else{
    $Admin->setId($admin['txtMail']);
    setcookie('user_mail', $admin['txtMail'], (time() + (30 * 24 * 3600)));
    setcookie('user_id', $Admin->getId(), (time() + (30 * 24 * 3600)));
    setcookie('is_logged', true, (time() + (30 * 24 * 3600)));
    echo json_encode([
        "success" => true
    ]);
}
```

Agora na página de login, eu chamo o `$_COOKIE['user_id']` só pra verificar se está funcionando os cookies e o que me retorna é isso:

> Notice: Undefined index: user_id in C:\xampp\htdocs\Project_app\admin\login.php on line 7

Código abaixo:

```
<?php
    ob_start();
    session_start();
    if(isset($_COOKIE['is_logged']) && $_COOKIE['is_logged']){
        header("Location:   index.php");
    }
    echo $_COOKIE['user_id'];
    require_once('sealed/controllers/controller.php');
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Ficou faltando definir o caminho ou rota onde a cookie poderá ser utilizada dentro do domínio. Por padrão, a cookie poderá ser utilizada no diretório onde foi criada e em seus subdiretórios. Se indicamos "/" a cookie terá validade dentro de todo o domínio.

```
setcookie('user_id', $Admin->getId(), time() + (30 * 24 * 3600), "/");
```

Answer (score -1):

Tente retirar os parênteses antes de `time()`.

Seu código:

```
setcookie('user_mail', $admin['txtMail'], (time() + (30 * 24 * 3600)));
```

Documentação PHP 7:

```
setcookie("CookieTeste", $value, time()+3600);
```

Seu novo código ficaria algo como:

```
setcookie("user_mail", $admin['txtMail'], time() + (30 * 24 * 3600));
echo $_COOKIE['user_id'];
```